# How to select Year only from time function?

Tags: php, mysql

am a newbie on mysql but i have a database having a table with `Date` column, i want to select "only" a year or a month or a day on the same row within a column here is my code (i used now() function to store the data

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM latest_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row['Date']; }
}
?>
```

-->  My Database table was

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `latest_news` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Message` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Date` date NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

--> having the stored values as

```
INSERT INTO `latest_news` (`Title`, `Message`, `Date`) VALUES
('Ufunguzi Ofisi ya Masaki', 'Mkurugenzi afungua Ofisi kwa furaha', NOW());
```

"Please help how can i select only a year from the row ? "

[my html where the year will be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9g0lH.jpg)

Comment: Use the YEAR() function to return the year part. Google mysql date functions for other useful functions

Comment: $sql = "SELECT YEAR(`Date`) as date FROM latest_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"; this also is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT `ID`,`Title`,`Message`,YEAR(`Date`) as Date FROM latest_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you but it says Notice: Undefined index: Date in C:\wamp64\www\Clarity\sample.php on line 43 of which the line 43 is echo $row['Date'];

Comment: check the edited answer you just have to make d capital in query

Answer (score 0):

This one now works, thanks Guys Sloan Thrasher and Vivek Modi, but on the month can I get alphabetical instead of numeric? let say it says 6 can we get June? how to do that?

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT YEAR(`date`) as Date FROM latest_news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['Date'];

        }
    }
?>
```